# Multidimensional array in html table

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `groupeditems` that looks like that:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo1”]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "658"
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "658"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "Flying Foxes"
      ["song_name"]=>
      string(12) "Flying Foxes"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "Moby"
      ["song_artist"]=>
      string(4) "Moby"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "1232"
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "1232"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Memory Gospel"
      ["song_name"]=>
      string(13) "Memory Gospel"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "Moby"
      ["song_artist"]=>
      string(4) "Moby"
          }
  }
  [“foo2”]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2047"
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2047"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "Yesterday"
      ["song_name"]=>
      string(9) "Yesterday"
      [2]=>
      string(11) "The Beatles"
      ["song_artist"]=>
      string(11) "The Beatles"
          }
     }
}
```

And I would like to echo this array in an html table so it looks like that :

```
<h2> foo1 <h2>

      flying foxes          moby                 
      memory gospel         moby                     

<h2> foo2 <h2>

      yesterday         the beatles
```

I am using the following PHP :

```
foreach ($groupedItems as $mks){
    echo "<table>"; 
     echo '<h2>';
     echo $mks[0];
     echo '</h2>';
         foreach ($mks as $qid=>$rate){
            echo "<tr><td>".$rate[1]."</td><td>".$rate[2]."</td></tr>";
          }
   echo "</table>";
    }
```

However, `$mks[0]` is not being displayed, It is supposed to show "foo1" or "foo2" and it just prints "Array" instead. I am certainly doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
foreach ($groupitems as $key => $foo) {
    echo '<h2>' . $key . '</h2>' . '<br>';
    foreach ($foo as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['id'] . $value['song_name'] . $value['song_artist'];
        echo <br>;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure though why you have the same values twice (once in an integer index and once in a string index). Before outputting anything you should choose one of the two and stay consistent with it.

Cheers.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for your advise I'm gonna do that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your array, remove the redundant parts i.e.

```
  [0]=>           # this is redundant, remove
  string(3) "658" # this is redundant, remove
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "658"
```

so your array would look something like this:

```
    Array
(
    [foo1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 658
            [song_name] => flying Floxes
            [song_artist] => moby
        )

    [foo2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 68
            [song_name] => flying
            [song_artist] => mo
        )

)
```

then do:

```
foreach ($a as $key=>$mks){
    echo "<table>"; 
     echo '<h2>';
     echo $key;
     echo '</h2>';
         foreach ($mks as $qid=>$rate){
            echo "<tr><td>".$qid."</td><td>".$rate."</td></tr>";
          }
   echo "</table>";
    }
```

hope this helps